# How can I solve this question by using while loop and slicing in python?

Tags: python

How can I solve a problem in which I have to Input as a number from the user and output its digits, "one digit per line". For example, if the user inputs 7854, then my program should output: The digits of 7854 are:
4
5
8
7

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: what have you tried for yourseelf?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Do you have some code to share on what you have tried and the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should be, but always try before asking:

```
v1 = input('Digits: ')
for n in v1[::-1]:
    print(int(n), end='\n')
```

Result:

```
Digits: 456
6
5
4
```

Comment: You don't need the call to `int` and you can drop the `end` parameter.

Comment: @Matthias as he needed digits, I just called `int` function. Regarding `end` parameter, I know it's optional in this case but I add it just for sure.